# Infinite Loop Issue in Node.js Post Recommendation System

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, while-loop, redis

I'm facing an issue with a post recommendation system in my Node.js app. It seems to be stuck in an infinite loop when attempting to fetch posts for a user. I suspect this might be happening when the user has already seen all available posts or when the maximum attempt count is reached without finding new posts.

I'm struggling to figure out a clean way to recognize when all posts have been viewed or when there are no new posts to recommend within the specified attempts. The system currently returns the same set of posts if all have been viewed, leading to redundancy.

If you have any insights or suggestions on how to gracefully handle these scenarios and ensure the system returns an empty array when there are no new posts to recommend, I'd greatly appreciate your help!

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```js
const LoadForYou = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;

        if (!authorizationHeader || !CheckAuthorizationHeader(authorizationHeader)) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                status: 400,
                error: "invalid_authorization_header",
                error_description: "Invalid or missing Authorization header",
            });
        }

        const token = authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1];
        const userId = await ValidateToken(token);

        if (!userId) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                status: 400,
                error: "invalid_token",
                error_description: "Invalid token",
            });
        }

        const db = Database.db("server");
        const collection = db.collection("posts");
        const blockedUsers = await db.collection("blocked").find({ $or: [{ user_id: userId }, { blocked_user_id: userId }] }).toArray();
        const blockedUserIdsCombined = [...blockedUsers.map((user) => user.blocked_user_id), userId, "B36093911098891690", "B71876368029587810"];

        const maxAttempts = 100;
        let postData = [];

        let attemptCount = 0;

        // Attempt to get posts until all non-private or non-friends-only posts are viewed
        while (attemptCount < maxAttempts) {
            const result = await collection.aggregate([
                { $match: { type: "post", archived: false, deleted: false } },
                { $sample: { size: 2 } },
                { $match: { "private": { $in: ["public", "friends"] } } },
                { $match: { creator_id: { $nin: blockedUserIdsCombined } } },
            ]).toArray();

            console.log("Attempt #" + attemptCount);

            const selectedPosts = await Promise.all(result.map(async (post) => {
                const postId = post.id;
                const creatorId = post.creator_id;

                let includePost = true;

                // Check if the post is only visible to friends and if the user is friends with the creator
                if (post.private === "friends" && !(await UserFriends(userId, creatorId))) {
                    includePost = false;
                }

                // Check if the user has already viewed the post
                if (includePost && !(await hasUserViewed(postId, userId))) {
                    includePost = false;
                }

                return includePost ? post : null;
            }));

            const filteredPosts = selectedPosts.filter((post) => post !== null);

            postData = postData.concat(filteredPosts);

            if (postData.length >= 2) {
                break;
            }

            attemptCount++;
        }

        return res.status(200).json({
            status: 200,
            postData,
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            status: 500,
            error: "internal_server_error",
            error_description: "An internal server error occurred",
        });
    }
};

async function hasUserViewed(postId, userId) {
    try {
        const [hasViewed, addViewCountFromUser] = await Promise.all([
            Redis.sismember(`user:${userId}:viewed_posts`, postId),
            Redis.sismember(`post:${postId}:views`, userId)
        ]);

        // If the post has not been viewed, mark it as viewed
        if (hasViewed === 0) {
            await Redis.sadd(`user:${userId}:viewed_posts`, postId);
        }

        if (addViewCountFromUser === 0) {
            await Redis.sadd(`post:${postId}:views`, userId);
        }

        return hasViewed;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
}

module.exports = LoadForYou;
```

I tried implementing a loop to fetch posts for a user, but it seems to get stuck when the user has already seen all available posts or when the maximum attempt count is reached without finding new ones.